# How does Hadoop split and combine its output data?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I think my question would be best explained with an example.  Say that you're storing an image on HDFS.  That image is large enough that it's split into four separate, smaller files on HDFS.  When you perform an operation that returns that image, does Hadoop return those 4 small files that can be combined back into the original image?  Or does Hadoop automatically recombine the 4 small files back into the original?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hadoop Distributed File System (HDFS) stores each file in one or more blocks (with each block being replicated one or more times).

For every file, you can configure the file block size and the replication factor (default values are used if not provided).

When you do any file based operation, you're dealing with streams of data, the Name Node is the central repository mapping file paths to blocks and their locations (data nodes).

Using an example, say you have a file block size of 32 MB, and a 50MB file - this will be split into 2 blocks (32 MB & 18 MB). If the configured replication factor of the file is say 3, then the NameNode will try and ensure that each block is replicated to 3 data nodes in your cluster.

When you try and read from this file, you're returned an FSInputStream, which like most input streams, you can seek to a certain byte position in the file. The DFSClient is abstracting you away from the details, but it knows for a particular byte offset, which block this relates to and seamlessly acquires the bytes (even as you step between block boundaries).

So to summarize and address your question - to the client reading from HDFS, it looks like one continuous input stream, but it's actually 4 blocks stitched together as required

Comment: That information about the FSInputStream is exactly what I needed.  Sorry the wording on my question was so poor!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that example is quite how Hadoop would normally be used.

However, if your result is a large file, then it will be *stored* in HDFS as smaller sub-files. If you retrieve it via HDFS filesystem operations, then it will be *returned* as a single logical file.

Comment: Okay, along those same lines, how is data stored long-term in a Hadoop environment?  Would you store the files in HDFS or in a separate database such as HBase?  For example, if one wanted to store a large amount of imagery metadata for later analysis, would that data be on HDFS or a separate database?  Thanks!

Comment: It depends entirely on what you want to do with it, not so much on the timescale of storage - I don't think I can give any advice (not that I am any expert on Hadoop/HDFS) without a specific use case.

Comment: There are a lot aspects to be considered to store data in Hadoop environments and there a lot of options also. It won't be a straight cut answer.